GSAP in react timeline is boundicng when I use ScrollTriggers
my react gsap comonent is not working i try to make scrub using timelines but it is not worcking correctly when i scroll down it is bounicng sometimes and soemtimes dont boucing hellpme to make my website more dinamic
i ty use css classes tyy muliple ways to avoid this bouncing I'm having trouble with my GSAP animations in React. I'm trying to implement scroll-based animations using timelines and scrub, but it's not working correctly. When I scroll down, the animations sometimes bounce and sometimes they don’t.
THIS IS THE CODE
function Services() {
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
useEffect(() => {
    // Scroll animation
    const tl = gsap.timeline({
        yoyo: true,
        scrollTrigger: {
            trigger: "#H",
            start: "30 top",
            end: 'bottom',
            scrub: true,
        }
    })
    tl.fromTo("#H0", { yPercent: 0 }, { yPercent: 0, duration: 1, ease: "none" })
        .fromTo("#H1", { yPercent: 0 }, { yPercent: -86, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 0)
        .fromTo("#H2", { yPercent: 0 }, { yPercent: -86, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 0)
        .fromTo("#H3", { yPercent: 0 }, { yPercent: -86, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 0)
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------ 1
        .fromTo("#H0", { yPercent: 0 }, { yPercent: 0, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 1)
        .fromTo("#H1", { yPercent: -86 }, { yPercent: -86, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 1)
        .fromTo("#H2", { yPercent: -86 }, { yPercent: -170, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 1)
        .fromTo("#H3", { yPercent: -86 }, { yPercent: -170, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 1)
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------ 2
        .fromTo("#H0", { yPercent: 0 }, { yPercent: 0, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 2)
        .fromTo("#H1", { yPercent: -86 }, { yPercent: -86, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 2)
        .fromTo("#H2", { yPercent: -170 }, { yPercent: -170, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 2)
        .fromTo("#H3", { yPercent: -170 }, { yPercent: -256, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 2)
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------ 3
        .fromTo("#H3", { yPercent: -256 }, { yPercent: -333, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 3)
        .fromTo("#H2", { yPercent: -170 }, { yPercent: -222, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 3)
        .fromTo("#H1", { yPercent: -86 }, { yPercent: -112, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 3)
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------ 4 
        .fromTo("#H0", { yPercent: 0 }, { yPercent: 0, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 4)
        .fromTo("#M", { height: "100%" }, { height: ` ${window.innerWidth > 1024 ? "40%" : window.innerWidth > 520 ? "40%" : "45%"}`, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 2)
        .fromTo("#M", { height: "45%" }, { height: ` ${window.innerWidth > 1024 ? "30%" : window.innerWidth > 520 ? "40%" : "45%"}`, duration: 1, ease: "none" }, 3)
    tl.seek(5)

    const tlM = gsap.timeline({
        scrollTrigger: {
            trigger: "#H",
            start: "top top",
            end: "bottom top",
            scrub: true,
        }
    })
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        .fromTo("#H", { yPercent: 0 }, { yPercent: 100, ease: "none" }, 0)
    ScrollTrigger.refresh()

}, [gsap]);

return (
    <div id='H' className='sm:pt-[3rem] w-full relative h-full flex flex-col items-center lg:p-[2rem] p-[1rem] pt-[2rem] sm:pb-[3rem] pb-[3rem]'>
        <div id='M' className='w-full absolute bg-white' />
        <div className='w-full mt-[4rem] relative xl:w-[68rem] justify-between flex lg:flex-row flex-col lg:text-start gap-[5rem] sm:p-0 p-[1rem] font-normal'>
            <div id="S" className='lg:flex relative grid lg:text-start text-center flex-col lg:items-start items-center gap-5'>
                <h2 className={`${headingText[0].primaryHeadingSmall} `}>Choose Your {window.innerWidth > 1024 && <br />} Design Adventure</h2>
                <p className={`${headingText[0].secondaryParagraph}`}>{serviceHeading[0].p}</p>
                <Button className='lg:justify-start justify-center' />
            </div>
            <div id='HM' className='grid gap-[2rem]'>
                {serviceArray.map((item, index) => (
                    <div id={`H${index}`} key={index} className='flex relative bg-white shadow-md h-[18.5rem] p-[2rem] rounded-2xl flex-col gap-[1rem]'>
                        <div className='flex items-center gap-[.5rem]'>
                            <div className='text-[1.4rem] bg-orange-400 rounded-full text-white p-[.5rem]'>
                                <IconRenderer img={item.img} alt={item.h3} />
                            </div>
                            <h3 className={`fs-secondary-400 font-bold text-gray-800`}>{item.h3}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <p className={`lg:max-w-[28rem] w-full opacity-[.7] ${headingText[0].secondaryParagraph}`}>{item.p}</p>
                        <div id='Line' />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)

}
I've tried multiple CSS classes to avoid this bouncing, but nothing seems to work. I need help making my website more dynamic and ensuring the animations are smooth.
